# How to pass variable to a BootStrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, modal-dialog

I would like to get help with passing a variable to a bootstrap modal.  I had code working prior to this but I was creating a new modal for each "conversation" that a user had (had something that was generating unique names for the modals based off of the username of the user, so each modal had a unique name and could be called).

I figured just passing some variables to the modal and generating the SQL to pull the 'messages' from the DB for those variables was probably a better coding practice and design overall so I am trying to get this working.

I ran into an issue with 1) not understanding jquery completely yet and 2) how to pass a variable from jquery to php.  I know I will need a SCRIPT tag with some JS/Jquery stuff.. So far I have the following.. (**all help is appreciated!**)

```
<?php 

//Message Center

//Query to look for unique users who have sent a message to the user, ordered by last person to send a message
$sql = "SELECT m.mFrom, MAX(m.date) as date, m.mTo, u.first, u.username, u.id 
        FROM messages m 
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.mFrom 
        WHERE mTo = '".$userId."' 
        GROUP BY mFrom
        ORDER BY date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo "<h3 class=\"text-center\">Message Center</h3>";
echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\"><tr><th>From</th><th>Last Message Received</th><th>Unread?</th><th>Conversation</th></tr>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["first"]."</td><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>glyphicon here</td>
        <td>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row["id"]."' href='#messagesModal'>See Conversation</button>
        </td></tr>";
    }
        echo "
            <div class='modal fade' id='messagesModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
              <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                <div class='modal-content'>

                  <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Conversation with ".$row["first"]."</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class='modal-body'>";

                  //Query to pull all the messages between the user and other user
                  $sql2 = "SELECT id, mFrom, message, date 
                            FROM messages 
                            WHERE (mFrom = '".$row["mFrom"]."' AND mTo = '".$userId."')
                            OR (mFrom = '".$userId."' AND mTo = '".$row["mFrom"]."') 
                            LIMIT 50";

                  $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
                  while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
                      if ($userId == $row2["mFrom"]){
                        echo "<div class=\"text-right\"><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><small>".$row2["date"]."</small><br>".$row2["message"]."</div></div><br>";
                      }
                      else{
                          echo "<div class=\"text-left\"><div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'><small>".$row2["date"]."</small><br>".$row2["message"]."</div></div><br>";
                      }
                  }

              echo "</div>
                      <div class='modal-footer'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Variable to Bootstrap Modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296180/javascript-variable-to-bootstrap-modal)