# How to bring a Javascript variable into a modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I found this javascript to calculate (on form submit) the sum of all input fields with class="qt". If the sum of all fields is less than 15 it shows a message in a javascript alert popup. So far so good.
But I don't like the style of the Javascript alert popup and it seems it cannot be styled. Therefore, instead of the standard Javascript alert popup I want to show the  message in a styled modal dialog. So far so good, still.
The only thing I can't figure out is how to bring the value of the Javascript variable (sum) into the modal window and show it there.

The form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="return calculateSum(this);" method="post" name="order" id="order" action="confirm.php">
```

The Javascript (external file: javascript.js):

```
function calculateSum() {

var sum = 0;
//iterate through each textboxes and add the values
$(".qt").each(function() {

//add only if the value is number
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
sum += parseFloat(this.value);
}

});
if(sum<15) {
//alert('Please order at least 15 boxes.\n\nYour current selection is ' + sum + '.');
$(document).ready(function(){$("#myModal").modal("show"); });
return false;
}
else {
return true;
//return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
}
}
```

The (Bootstrap) modal to show (html):

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
<div class="modal-content">

<!-- Modal Header -->
<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>

<!-- Modal body -->
<div class="modal-body">
<!--HOW CAN I SHOW THE JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE (sum) HERE?-->
</div>

<!-- Modal footer -->
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate question. [Check answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296180/javascript-variable-to-bootstrap-modal) I think it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the message in your ready callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modal-body").html("Please order at least 15 boxes.\n\nYour current selection is " + sum + "."); 
  $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty `<p>` tag (or however you want to display this in the modal) to your modal HTML, and give it an `id` that you will use in the Javascript. Then, you will replace the `innerHTML` of the tag in the script with your variable:

```
function calculateSum() {
var sum = 0;
//iterate through each textboxes and add the values
$(".qt").each(function() {
//add only if the value is number
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
sum += parseFloat(this.value);
}
});
if(sum<15) {
//alert('Please order at least 15 boxes.\n\nYour current selection is ' + sum + '.');
$(document).ready(function(){$("#myModal").modal("show"); });
return false;
}
else {
return true;
//return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
}
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML=sum;
}
} 
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
            <!--HOW CAN I SHOW THE JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE (sum) HERE?-->
            <p id="sum"></p>
         </div>
         <!-- Modal footer -->
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```