# How to display selected button value from a bootstrap modal to a primary button

Tags: html

So I am using a bootstrap Modal to display my list of buttons, however I am not using the select method for certain purposes, I am just displaying my button list in a modal. I want to display the value of a button which is pressed in a modal, in my primary button.

This is my button, which when pressed opens a bootstrap modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" 
   id="fSum" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable"> 

   NEEDED VALUE TO BE DISPLAYED 
   <span class="badge badge-light float-right">V</span>
</button>
```

This is my modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Choose:</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical w-100" role="group">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" *ngFor="let item of product" (click)="postSum()">
              {{item.amount}}
           </button>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment:    `{{item.amount}}` is an array which creates a button list in a modal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Variable to Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296180/javascript-variable-to-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: `button` does not have a `value` property. Did you mean `textContent`?